# I am trying to show the most loaned item in a current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, max

The question is to find the most loaned resource in the current month. Print the resource id and resource name. Note: “current month” must be decided by the system.

**Table Loan**

```sql
Create Table Loan(
LoanId Varchar(10),
ResourceId Varchar(10),
MemberId Varchar(10),
DateBorrowed Date,
DateReturned Date,
DateDue Date,
TimeBorrowed Time(0),
TimeReturned Time(0),
TimeDue Time(0),
Primary Key(LoanId)
,Foreign Key (MemberId) references Member(MemberId)
,Foreign Key (ResourceId) references Resources(ResourceId)
)
```

**Loan Inputs**

```sql
Insert into Loan values('L1', 'R001', 'c1', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-1', '09:00:00', '10:00:00', '17:00:00')
Insert into Loan values('L2', 'R902', 'c1', '2022-9-11', '2022-9-18', '2022-9-18', '11:00:00', '10:00:00', '17:00:00')
Insert into Loan values('L3', 'R003', 'S5', '2020-6-5', '2020-6-6', Null, '09:00:00', '17:00:00', Null)
Insert into Loan values('L4', 'R905', 'S5', '2022-10-4', '2022-10-8', Null, '09:00:00', '17:00:00', Null)
Insert into Loan values('L5', 'R905', 'c2', '2022-10-16', '2022-10-18', '2021-2-18', '13:00:00', '08:30:00', '17:00:00')
```

**Table Resources**

```sql
Create Table Resources(
ResourceId Varchar(10),
Name Varchar(25),
Manufacturer Varchar(20),
Model varchar(4),
Capacity INT,
Year INT,
AssetValue Int,
Description VarChar(50),
Status Varchar(10),
BorrowNumber INT,
Primary Key (ResourceId),
Foreign Key (BorrowNumber) references Category(BorrowNumber) ,
Unique(Name)
```

**Resource Inputs**

```sql
Insert into Member values('S1', Null, 1, 'Gary Coleman', '4th Street', 0413111111, 'G.C@uni.com', 'Staff', 'Active', 'Head of the Uni')
Insert into Member values('S2', 'MATH101', 1, 'Emma Champ', 'Winner Street', 0413222222, 'E.C@uni.com', 'Staff', 'Active', 'Very Cheerful')
Insert into Member values('S3', 'STAT205', 1, 'Jack Loser', 'Help Lane', 0413333333, 'J.L@uni.com', 'Staff', 'Active', 'Will Leave at the end of the year')
Insert into Member values('S4', 'PHYS408', 1, 'Henry Cold', 'Cross Road', 0413444444, 'H.C@uni.com', 'Staff', 'Active', 'New starter')
Insert into Member values('S5', 'CHEM211', 1, 'Billie Danger', 'Stand Cove', 0413555555, 'B.D@uni.com', 'Staff', 'Active', 'No Comment')
Insert into Member values('c1', 'MATH101', 2, 'Amelia Strange', 'West Avenue', 0313111111, 'A.S@uni.com', 'Student', 'Active', 'No Comment')
Insert into Member values('c2', 'MATH101', 2,'Gabby Kale', 'North Parade', 0313222222, 'G.K@uni.com', 'Student', 'Active', 'A+ Student')
Insert into Member values('c3', 'STAT205', 2, 'Hannah Howard', 'South Close', 0313333333, 'H.H@uni.com', 'Student', 'Active', 'Failing Student')
Insert into Member values('c4', 'PHYS408', 2, 'Lesley Cold', 'East House', 0313444444, 'L.C@uni.com', 'Student', 'Inactive', 'Old Student')
Insert into Member values('c5', 'CHEM211', 2, 'Stacy Strange', 'West Avenue', 0313111112, 'S.S@uni.com', 'Student', 'Active', 'No Comment')
```

I am having trouble first ordering by the max count and have the code below as an example

```sql
Select Name, R.ResourceId, t1.Count
from Resources R
Left Join (
    Select ResourceId, count(ResourceId) as Count
    from Loan
    Group By ResourceId
) as t1 on t1.ResourceId = R.ResourceId
```

Comment: It would be better to share your tables' schema with more detailed sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code, adding an `ORDER BY` statement at the bottom would sort the list.

```
Select Name, R.ResourceId, t1.Count
from Resources R
Left Join (
    Select ResourceId, count(ResourceId) as Count
    from Loan
    Group By ResourceId
) as t1 on t1.ResourceId = R.ResourceId
ORDER BY t1.Count DESC  --Order the results by the count, DESC = biggest number at the top.
```

If it's more complicated than this, then you need to explain more. I'm not even sure why you show the Member table if it's not involved.